# Kit Selection for android Qt application development

Tags: android, qt, qt-necessitas

I am developing a new application for android device. When I create a new project “Kit Selection” menu has come. I am confused which to add. And which kit I should use to build my application.

Can you explain what are the kits below:

1. Android for armeabi (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1)
2. Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1)
3. Android for x86 (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1)
4. Desktop-Qt 5.2.1 for Android x86

Comment: The first two are for tablets and phone (ARMs) and the latter for desktop. There is no universal "catch-all" option. Is there anything more you would like to know?

Comment: ARM refers to the processor? So if I build using option 1, I can use it for all android tablets and phones?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-2/) and [this](http://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-3/)?

Comment: The above links says only about option 2. And not describing what is that.

Comment: Oopsie, "first two" should read as "first three". Either way, the first three are for different architectures, the first two are for different arm and the third is for x86 based tablets, like Intel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **armeabi: (For Android phone or tablet)** It will run on ARMv5 and ARMv6 like ARM9 or ARM11. this will work fine on all devices, but will be a lot slower, and won't take advantage of newer devices' CPU capabilities.
- **armeabi-v7a:(For Android phone or tablet)** Supports multi-core processors and will run on Cortex A#
  devices like Cortex A8, A9, and A15. It also has support for hardware
  floating point operations which makes your application faster.
- **Android for x86: (For Android phone or tablet)** This is for x86 CPU architectures.
- **Desktop-Qt 5.2.1: (For Desktop)** This is for x86 CPU architectures.

Comment: could you provide some link so that I can read more about this?

Comment: You want to know more about Qt Kits or difference between armeabi and armeabi-v7a?

Comment: Nice answer. I think something like this should be added to the official Qt(Creator?) documentation, too.

Comment: @Abin You can read http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html for more information about Kits.